# An interface that "extends itself" is ensuring what?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, interface, restriction

I was following a tutorial for an EventBus in and came across the following Interface:

```
public interface IEventHandler<in TEvent> : IEventHandler where TEvent : Event
{
    Task Handle(TEvent @event);
}

public interface IEventHandler
{

}
```

Now, I get the generics part and the restriction, but I'm missing the point where the Interface extends itself. 
It's the first time I've seen it being used like this. What does it accomplish?
Can anybody please shed some light on this subject? Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think the interface implements itself? The generic interface extends the non-generic interface. That can be useful if you want some code to be able to deal with *any* event handler, and other code only be able to deal with *specific* event handlers.

Comment: It is simply not possible for the interface to implement itself. How you can declare an interface and at the same time implement itself undeclared?

Comment: yep. I get it now @JonSkeet

Comment: They are interfaces with the same name, but differentiated by a generic type parameter (thus, they are different). Also note that you can't do this in languages like Java, Kotlin or _TypeScript_ since GTPs are erased at compile time. Since GTPs are visible to the CLR at runtime, `IEventHandler<T>` and `IEventHandler` are distinguishable from one another. (Note TypeScript (above) in italics, because you can achieve similar functionality like so: `interface IEventHandler<T = any> { ... }`)

Answer (score 3):

In C# the types `Interface` and `Interface<T>` (you will sometimes see this as `` Interface`1 ``) are distinct types. They have no relation inside the type system (unless one interface extends the other).

This can be confusing when you come from a Java background, where you have "raw types" and a `List<T>` is always a `List` at the same time. This is not true for C#.

You could rename the interfaces to make this distinction clearer:

```
IEventHandler<in TEvent> : IEventHandlerRaw
```

(this is only to make the explanation clearer. It is not recommended in production code)

Comment: I suspect naming a generic interface with the suffix `Generic` is bad style. So it might not be a great thing to do in real code.

Comment: @omajid: sure, I was only trying to point out that `A` and `A<T>` are different types, you could as well name them `A` AND `B<T>`. Nevertheless, I have edited my answer